# android map api overview and choice

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, leaflet, openlayers

I want to create an app with android studio that will use a map and show the device location on it. Also i want to show markers on the map and be able to click them and interact with them.
A lightweight and fast solution(there will be frequent updates of locations) is best of course.

I searched a bit and found the solution of google maps api.
This has an api solution for android but i then found other options like
leaflet, openlayers and probably there are more.
Leaflet though and openlayers are js and after searching how to implement it i found i have to use a "webview".
I could not find any other native solution like google maps that is as open source as leaflet or openlayers.
At first i though to use leaflet since google maps was not so open source and could ask for money after some use of the maps. Also i want to use custom markers.

*What library should i use?

Does using js and webview have a considerable impact on speed and performance over native libraries?

Is it difficult to interact with the js - to change/create markers, display text and stuff and move the marker as the user moves?

I am new to android development any advice that will point mistakes at my thinking are welcome.*

Answer (score -1):

The best approach is to develop a hybrid app so that you can bring the best of both JS and JAVA world together.

We have successfully developed a hybrid app based on leaflet for a large enterprise in India.

As as far as the hybrid apps are concerned, you can use Iconic framework. You can perform/customize all the map related functionalities which leaflet offers.

We have not seen any performance lag(tested on Android 4.4, 5.1 and 6.0)